# how create a square signal between 0.2 volt and 0.8 volt

Tags: arduino

i am working on a signal comparator. I want to create a signal output of 0.2 volt if the input is under reference value and 0.8 volt if the input is over the reference.  I am doing it with an arduino and usign a poteciometer to change the reference between 0.3 volt and 0.7 volt.

The input signal is changing between 0.85 and 0.05 volts with frecuency of 3 Hz as maximum.

This is the simulation suggested:

[image]

Comment: Why do you need such small values?

Comment: i am working with a O2 sensor. Those are the sensor voltages

Comment: Comparator followed by potential divider?

Comment: You can also use a DAC, depending on what square wave frequency you need.

Comment: Could you clarify what your input voltages are, it is hard to tell from your description.

Comment: The input signal is changing between 0.85 and 0.05 volts with  frecuency of 3 Hz as maximum

Comment: What is the part  number  of the comparator? Is it part of the ATMega chip or an external part? What is your supply voltage, 5V?

Comment: it is part of the atmega chip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Input:** To figure if the input is above or below your reference, you can use a comparator with one input being your signal and the other input being a voltage divider.  This is not shown in my answer.

> I am doing it with an arduino and usign a poteciometer to change the reference between 0.3 volt and 0.7 volt.

Alternatively, one can read the voltage on an Arduino ADC pin and compare to a (flexible!) digital reference.

**Output:** This circuit should work to create the voltage waveform to be controlled by an Arduino IO pin- you can then buffer the output of the voltage divider with a buffer opamp.

A transistor such as FDN327N will work well with 5V gate voltage.  The resistors might have to be slightly rescaled to give you more precise voltage.  I just did a rough calculation.

\$ V_{outL} = 0.2V = V_{cc} × R_2/(R_2+R_3) \$

\$ V_{outH} = 0.8V = V_{cc} × (R_2+R_1)/(R_1+R_2+R_3) \$

First select \$R_3\$, then calculate \$R_2\$, then \$R_1\$.

*Note that the logic is inverted- high IO pin output results in 0.2V and vice-versa.*
[image]

[image]

Comment: He said that the reference voltage is 0.3V (minimum). Which I belive means that the output would have to be (0.8V) when there is more than 0.3V at the gate of the MOSFET. And 0.2V otherwise. I dont think this can be done the way you purposed.

Comment: @Golaž right, it's a bit unclear to me too.  That's why I have modified the answer a bit

Comment: Also, it assumes the output is feeding a high impedance, which may or may not be true.

Comment: the resistors values give me an output betweenn 0.4 and 0.8 [mV]

Comment: @ArturoVeras The resistor values are fine.  Make sure you have selected a MOSFET that can fully turn on with 5V gate.  Alternatively, you can just plug in a NPN- 2222 BJT with 1k Ohm resistor between the 5V comparator output and the BJT base.

Comment: i am using the IRFZ44N transistor
[datasheet](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/17807/PHILIPS/IRFZ44N.html)

I do not understand where to put the transistor.

Comment: @ArturoVeras First, you need to specify the transistor in LTspice -> right click on NMOS and select your part, if it is there.  Also, the transistor you selected requires at least 10V turn-on signal.

Comment: @SunnyBoyNY you were right i picked up a new nmos and i it work.

Comment: @SunnyBoyNY the problem is that i cannot find a 5v mosfet.

Comment: FDN327N will work just fine.  LTSpice might not have it built-in.  Alternatively you can use the 2N2222 BJT with 1k base resistor instead of the MOSFET.

Comment: In the post i show you the circuit. it works but, what are those peaks voltages of the square output signal ?

Comment: This seems to be related to the npn model.  Try changing the base resistor to 100k and decreasing the other resistor by a factor of 10 (10k, 410, 1.47k).  This will diminish the effect of npn leakage currents.

Answer (score 2):

As you are comparing two analogue signals, the following circuit would work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP0Awy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This schematic assumes that the comparator is an open-drain (or open-collector) type device, which are commonly available.

The resistor values are one way to get the desired voltage, but are not standard values. To find the relationship between the resistor values you basically need to use potential divider equations such that in one state you have:

$$0.2 = V_{cc} \times \frac{R_c || R_b}{(R_c || R_b) + R_t}$$

And in the other state:

$$0.8 = V_{cc} \times \frac{R_b}{R_b + R_t}$$

After a bit of algebra, and assuming you use a \$+5\mathrm{V}\$ supply, you get:

$$R_t = 5.25 \times R_b$$
$$R_c = 0.28 \times R_b$$

This will produce \$0.8\mathrm{V}\$ when the signal is greater than the reference. It will produce \$0.2\mathrm{V}\$ when the signal is smaller than the reference.

---

Note: if the comparator is not open drain, or you use a rail-to-rail op-amp it is possible to adjust the equations so that in the one for \$0.8=\$, replace \$R_t\$ with \$(R_t || R_c)\$.

Answer (score 0):

I built a circuit model for the rail-to-rail op-amp configuration described above.

Here is the Wolfram Alpha string that does the described algebra:

eqn {0.2 = 5*(1/(1/r_1+1/r_2))/(r_3+(1/(1/r_1+1/r_2))); 0.8=5*(r_2)/(r_2+(1/(1/r_1+1/r_3)));r_2=1000} for r_3,r_1

(or go to this link sysvis.io/YpCalT)

This results in R3=21K, R1=7K, for R2=1K

(R3=Rt; R1=Rc; R2=Rb)

Here is a www.systemvision.com circuit that implements this configuration:
http://sysvis.io/ODRMAG

[image]

this produces the 0.2V to 0.8V square wave.

Comment: i did this and the output got stuck in 220 mV. i choose an LT1721 rail-to-rail oamp.